# When did David hope to see the Lord? (Psalm 17:15)

Tags: psalms

When did David hope to see the Lord?

Psalm 17:15

> <sup>15</sup> As for me, I will behold thy face in righteousness: I shall be satisfied, when I awake, with thy likeness. <sup>KJV, ©1769</sup>

Answer (score 1):

David hoped to see Yavheh When he awoke, the awakening being a reference to the resurrection of the dead, since sleep is a reference to death.<sup>1</sup>

The prophet Isaiah wrote,<sup>2</sup>

> Your dead will **come back to life**; your corpses will **rise up**. **Wake up** and shout joyfully, you who live in the ground! For you will grow like plants drenched with the morning dew, and the earth will bring forth its dead spirits. <sup>NET, ©1996</sup>

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Psa. 13:3 cf. John 11:13
<sup>2</sup> Isa. 26:19

Answer (score -1):

Psalm 17 is prayer (v1, 4) of David for final vindication (v2).  He seeks protection from God (v5-14).

The final verse has several elements that are answered elsewhere in the Bible.

- David hopes for perfect righteousness.  1 Cor 15:50ff discusses the sort of people we will be when resurrected as does Rev 14:5.
- David Hopes to see God face to face - this is the reward of the righteous as recorded in Rev 22:4 in the New Jerusalem.  Job 19:27 expresses the same future hope.
- David says this will occur when he awakes (ie from sleep).  In the New Testament, sleep is used as a synonym for death in John 11:11, 14, Luke 7:14, 1 Thess 4:14, 16, etc.  This is clearly an allusion to those who awake at the resurrection (see also Ps 13:3, Isa 26:19 which makes the same connection).  See also Acts 7:60, 13:36, 1 Cor 7:39, 11:30, 15:6, 51, 2 Peter 3:4, etc.
- Lastly, there is a difference in the way some versions translate the final phrase.  The KJV & YLT and some others have "awake with your likeness" is a request for God to fulfil His promise to make us like Him 1 Cor 3:18, 1 John 3:2, etc.  This obviously occurs at the resurrection of the saints.

Thus, there are numerous references here to the final resurrection of the saints when they awake from the graves.  [Side note - the English "cemetery" come from the Greek "koimeterion" = a place of sleeping.]